# How do you write something in mod form?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I was given the question: A band of 17 pirates has stolen a chest of gold coins. When they try to divide the coins into equal portions, 3 coins are left over.

Could this then be written as $z \equiv 17 \mbox{ mod } 3$?

Comment: It's actually $3\pmod{17}$. One way to think of it is, when you divide the number of coins by $17$, there are $3$ left over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write it as congruence
$$
z \equiv 3 \pmod{17}
$$
meaning the left hand side having the same remainder like the right hand side, under division by  $17$ or via the modulo operator
$$
z \bmod 17 = 3
$$
stating the remainder.

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean $z \equiv 3 \pmod{17}$?

Yes, of course, meaning that $z$ gives remainder $3$ when divided by $17$.

Therefore you'll have $z=3+17k$ , being $k$ an integer number.